# Full Calendar ASP.NET MVC update database eventDragStop

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, fullcalendar

Does anybody have any idea how I can update my underlying datasource (sql server DB) when making changes in a JQUERY UI Full Calendar?

I have the FullCalendar plugin enabled and working, also being populated with data, I have enabled the dragging and dropping options and they work, obviously these changes are not being committed to the database and I am unsure how to go about it, perhaps some kind of AJAX call to a method in my controller? Although I am unsure how to go about implementing even that.

Hope the question isn't too vague, just after a push in the right direction really.

Cheers

SOLUTION:

So the final solution looked like this:

ASP.NET MVC 5 CSHTML PAGE

```
@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

        },
        theme: false,
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: false,
        events: "/controller/GetEvents/",
        editable: true,
        eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
            var id = event.id;
            var start = event.start;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/controller/FullCalendarEventDrop/",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id: id, start: start}
            });
        }
    });

 });
// ]]></script>

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
public void FullCalendarEventDrop(int id, string start)
{
    DateTime startDt = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss UTC yyyy", null).ToUniversalTime();


    OBJECT OBJECTNAME = db.OBJECT.Find(id);
    _OBJECTNAME.StartDate = startDt;
    _OBJECTNAME.EndDate = startDt;

    db.Entry(OBJECTNAME).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

So there is no error handling as yet but i'll put that in, most importantly the updates work.

Thanks

:D

Comment: I have looked at the API docs and I know there are jquery callbacks triggered but unsure how to implement these also.

Comment: You could make an AJAX call on the [eventDrop](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) that passes data to a controller to handle the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [eventDrop](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) callback and pass the data via AJAX to your controller.

modified from the documentation...

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        // events here
    ],
    editable: true,
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/MyController/FullCalendarEventDrop",
            data: event
        });
    }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FullCalendarEventDrop(int id, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    //Get the event by the id and update its start/end

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Shoe's comments, you would probably also want to use the 'eventResize' event if your users are allowed to manipulate the days.  Write your "edits" via ajax and return via JSON as well to see those edits that were made.  In your cal's initialization:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        },
        events: '/SampleController/GetEvents',
```

Controller (call after edits made) or reinitialize events on cal load :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        var events = _buildSampleData.GetEventList();

        return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I would call this after edits have been made.

Comment: Thanks, I already had this bit implemented. will post my solution in a bit.